# Regex find every instance of element in html

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm scraping an html page that has X amount of instances of the element `class="page-title"` inside a div element `id="row-1"`

So we have something like:

```
<div id="row-1">
    <div class="page-title">
        <span><h4><a>text I want to grab</a></h4></span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

There could be 1,2,3,10 of these rows. Could anyone help explain how I can grab every instance of the page title if there are multiple rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't use a regex! [**HE COMES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead, use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_source_here);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@id='row-1']/div[@class='page-title']");
```